# Nullable Foreign Keys or Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 SQL tables:

```
Articles (ArticleId PK)
  |-- Chapters (ChapterId PK, ArticleId FK)
       |-- Sections (SectionId PK, ChapterId FK)
```

I have a fourth table, `Evaluations`, to store evaluations of `Articles`, `Chapters` or `Sections`:

```
Evaluations (
  EvaluationId PK,
  ArticleId NULLABLE FK,
  ChapterId NULLABLE FK,
  SectionId NULLABLE FK
)
```

If an Evaluation is for a Chapter I give a value to its `ChapterId` and leave `ArticleId` and `SectionId` empty.

Should I remove these 3 FKs and use 3 tables instead: `ArticleEvaluations`, `ChapterEvaluations`, `SectionEvaluations`?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As a [very] personal opinion I tend to separate these entities only if there are very compelling reasons to do so. Keeping them as a single one has many advantages in terms of development and maintenance: you need to deal with a single table and queries are much easier and fast, specially if you need to retrieve evaluations of all types at once. I would enforce **one and only one FK is not null** using a `CHECK` constraint in the table.

Comment: That was my next question ... Making sure that only one of those FK is defined ... Another option would be to have a superset table from which Articles, Chapters and Sections Derive and relate Tests to that table. Do you think that would be a better option?

Comment: The CHECK constraint can take the form: `check (ArticleId is not null and ChapterId is null and SectionId is null or ArticleId is null and ChapterId is not null and SectionId is null or ArticleId is null and ChapterId is null and SectionId is not null)
`.

Comment: What about structure of ArticleId, ChapterId and SectionId ? Is it possible that all these ID have similar structure (example: all are INTEGER) ?

Comment: @schlebe Yes they are all integer. You mean using a Superset table?

Comment: I don't know what is superset ! But if all Id are integers, you can replace all of them by 2 fields. First field define type of text (A or C or S) and second field cannot be NULL and defines related ID that is ArticleId or ChapterId or SectionId. You don't need any CHECK constraint except NOT NULL on TextId (second field)

Comment: @schlebe What happens if you add a reference to a type `'A'` with an `ArticleId` of `-42`, but there is no such article? A foreign key reference prevents a reference to a value that does not exist. What if an evaluation references an existing article, e.g. `42`, and the article is deleted? A foreign key reference prevents deleting rows that are referenced. Do you propose to implement that functionality with two columns and no `check` constraint? Perhaps with triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Many ways,

Create another table EvaluationObjectType and use its PK to the Evaluation table.

```
EvaluationID
EvaluationObjectTypeID (it can be the of one of the three type)
EvaluationObjectID ( chapterid/articleid/sectionid)
```

with this you won't be able to create an FK explicitly to chapter/article/section.

You should finalyse the design consdering its usage in queries such as in reporting and calculations.

Another option, is to create one combined table for Chapter, Article and Sections. Without seeing the data I can't advise it.

Comment: I think not using a FK can create some problems ... The other option you suggest is one I am considering. Having a "Base" table for Chapters, Articles and Sections. Then each of these tables would have an ID which would be both a PH and FK to Base table making a one to one relation. The only problem I see is that now the Ids in Articles, Chapters and Sections would not be sequential as they are shared by all. There cannot exist a Chapter with Id 1 and an Article with Id 1 ... Can't predict if this would be a problem.

Comment: I prefer option 1, if you can enforce the data integrity through other means..

Comment: Why is it impossible to have Chapter with id 1 and Article with Id 1 ? The 2 ids are integers but they are not linked. They must have their personal AUTO_INCREMENT field parameters. Can you give more explanations on how you are defining these ID ?